# Use MapViewOfFile to create a shared memory block, then placement new a class object on this block?

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory

I use function `CreateFileMapping` `MapViewOfFile` `UnmapViewOfFile` to create a shared block on the disk. Can I placement new a class object on this block?

---

I use VS2003 IDE.

```
try
{
    Sphere *pData = m_pBVH->GetFirstHalfData();
    Sphere *p = new(pData)Sphere(center, radius, index);
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    // Can't catch
}
```

Placement new error:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

At the `Debug` Mode, `placement new` operator may cause a syntax error. It's likely because of the code above, anotate it and try again!

At `Release` mode, it's OK, but throws exception which is not std::bad_alloc, can't figure out which it is. Maybe there is something with the way shared memory is built. My shared memory creation code is as bellow:

```
CBVHVertexBuffer::CBVHVertexBuffer(const CString &file, unsigned int size)
{
    this->file = file;
    this->size = size;

    fileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    mapHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    mapLength = 0;

    start = NULL;
    end = NULL;
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

    fileHandle = ::CreateFile(
        file,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,
        NULL);
    if (fileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        //::SetFilePointer(fileHandle, size * pickingVertexSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
        //::SetEndOfFile(fileHandle);
        //mapLength = ::GetFileSize(fileHandle, NULL);
        //mapLength = size * pickingVertexSize;
        mapHandle = ::CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size * pickingVertexSize, NULL);
        mapLength = ::GetFileSize(fileHandle, NULL);
        start = (Sphere*)::MapViewOfFile(mapHandle, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    end = start + size;

    Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would advice to only use Plain Old Data (POD) in your mapped file, because pointers can become invalid when mapping and unmapping files

Comment: Let's ignore whether the pointer is valid. Is it work that new a class object on the share block? And how?

Comment: It works with `placement new` and manually calling the destructor. Be prepared for manually bookkeeping pointer offsets

Comment: I use vs2003 IDE.`Sphere *pData = m_pBVH->GetFirstHalfData();`
`Sphere *p = new(pData)Sphere(center, radius, index);` It's wrong for syntax error `pData`.

Comment: @Merlin: _"Let's ignore whether the pointer is valid"_ -- Just to be sure you're talking of the same thing. The pointer to the allocated object is certainly valid (though no longer if you hand it to another process!), but if another process accesses your struct after correctly mapping the view, and there is a pointer within the struct (pointing at something in your address space), that pointer will still be _invalid_, even if it is valid from your point of view. Therefore the advice to stick with PODs is a good one.

Comment: @Damon My objects are non-PODs. Because there are a lot objects to be created and they may be needed `delete` and `new` times. So I want to use share block to pre-allocate a large memory.

Comment: @Merlin: As long as that's your only concern, this is perfectly OK then (unusual, but perfectly OK). Unless you either unmap-remap the view or try to map (and use the objects within) from another process, the pointer addresses remain valid (even non-POD).

Comment: @Damon As I mentioned at the question, what's wrong with my code? The `placement new` used like that on the net.

Comment: The exception can't come from placement new, since that doesn't throw. All it does is call the constructor and pass-through the pointer. It's probably something in your mapping code that goes weird. Note that the complicated `SetEndOfFile` dance and mapping the whole file is much more complicated than necessary (and possibly a source for errors). Creating _any_ non-zero size mapping will grow an empty file to of the required size (works reliably, I've done that a thousand times). It's also the fastest possible way. No need to do anything more complicated.

Comment: @Damon You meant that it's not necessary to call the `SetFilePointer` and `SetEndOfFile`, just annotate this two sentences?

Comment: @Merlin: Yes, read paragraph 2 under [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Damon I change my code shown at the questino. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Damon I add a function `Sphere* GetSpecifiedAddr(int pos)` to get the specified position address as the placement new address. And it works. Maybe `start` member of the class buffer is private.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you can use placement new operator (`void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw();`) to create an object in an already allocated memory buffer.

However, creating objects in file mapping regions should be applied for POD objects. Any raw pointer member (and virtual memory table if any) will not be recommended to be stored in mapped file, because they will be invalidated as soon as the mapping is done in a different address space. You should also take care to manage the memory allocation in this case.

I recommend to take a look at boost interprocess library (they have pretty good support for [memory mapped files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_mapped_files), including management of the memory buffers - allocation algorithms, object tracking and a pointer-like class for linking objects address-space independent ([offset_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html))).

Comment: Why shouldn’t you use virtual or pointers there? how is it different from any other memory page?

Comment: Memory mapped file means the content of the memory will be stored in the file. Next time you read the content in memory, it will not be at the same address, so raw addresses become invalid. See also some details here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html

Comment: @CătălinPitiș I check a lot solutions with my problem. Most of them are just like adding head file <new> or <memory>, it works for g++, but not for VS2003 IDE. Why? And can you give me a solution?

Comment: @CătălinPitiș But it's OK in `Release` Mode.